# Using enum in verilog

Tags: enums, verilog, quartus

I'm writting a piece of code in Quartus verilog (`.v`) and I'm trying to write a enum type inside my module:

```
module Controller(clk, IorD);

    enum {READ, DECODE} state;
    myState = READ;
    //...
```

But it gives me the following error: `Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at Controller.v(3) near text "{";  expecting ";"`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use a enum in verilog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enum` is a SystemVerilog feature. You will need to make sure that the file type in Quartus is SystemVerilog (usually the `.sv` extension is used too)

Comment: Unfortunately quartus won't allow me to create symbol files from `.sv`.

Answer (score 3):

You can instead use parameters in place of enums if you are restricted to using verilog only in the tool.
If you can switch to other tools try edaplayground(dot)com

example code as requested below:

```
localparam START =1;
localparam STOP  =2;
```

Use localparam instead of parameter because you really don't want these values to be changed during instantiation.

Comment: Could you give an example? Currently I'm using states as integers, something like `integer START = 1`, `integer STOP = 2`, etc., and I set the state as `state = START`, but this approach is ugly and I'd rather use enums.

Comment: If you would rather use enums find a tool that supports system verilog.

Answer (score 3):

`enum` is not a part of IEEE Std 1364-2005 specification (newest Verilog specification).

You have to use SystemVerilog which support `enum` or make a workaround in Verilog:

```verilog
parameter READ   = 'd 0;
parameter DECODE = 'd 1;

my_state = STATE_READ;
```

I suggest placing all parameters in second file with extension `.vh` (Verilog Header) and include them by  `` `include `` directive. For example:

```verilog
`include "parameters.vh"
```

You can also notice that I used `my_state` except `myState` because in Verilog naming conventions suggest to use lowercase with underscores (`_`) to separate words.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use typedef.

In your case =>

module Controller(clk, IorD);

```
typedef enum {READ, DECODE} state_e;

state_e myState;

//Now you can use myState ...
```

Comment: typedef is a SystemVerilog feature (.sv), not Verilog (.v)